# silverlight delete row with delete key

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I want to delete all the selected rows when the delete button is pressed.
I assumed that as log as the datagrid is bound to an `ObservableCollection` the effect of hitting delete was to delete the item from the collection.

It seems this is not working, here is what I've tried:

```
private void historyGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)        
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
  {
    foreach (Order item in historyGrid.SelectedItems)
    {
      history.Remove(item);
    } 
  }
}
```

But when I hit delete I get that the collection was changed and the enumeration might not work exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete items from a list you are iterating (or in this case a related list).

Create a temporary list of the items you want to delete and iterate that instead.

e.g.

```
List<Order> itemsToDelete = new List<Order>(historyGrid.SelectedItem);
foreach (Order item in itemsToDelete)
{
    history.Remove(item);
}
```

Or as [AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17516/anthonywjones) rightly suggests, just add a reference to Linq and change your code to

```
foreach (Order item in historyGrid.SelectedItems.ToList())
{
    history.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Or if you have the `using System.Linq` in place add `.ToList()` to the end of `SelectedItems` in the original code.